# Can I have separate tags lists for journal and todo/notes?

Tags: org-mode, org-tags

I use fixed tags for tasks and notes. These are tags either represent different physical places where I do my tasks (e.g. `@home` or `@errands`), or represent different areas of responsibility for me (e.g. `%FAMILY`, `%HOME`, `%CAR`). I define these tags by mean of `org-tag-alist`.

However, these tags are of little relevance when I want to tag my journal entries, which are mainly reflections of political, philosophical and ethical nature. Can I have another tag list for journal entries, or could I get a tag list to chose from which only consists of tags already used within the journal.org file? The %^g and %^G tools gives me all tasks used in my journal.org file AS WELL as those defined by `org-tag-alist`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the Org manual section on [Settings tags](http://orgmode.org/manual/Setting-tags.html). It sounds like you have multiple org files, so you can specify a set of tags per file using the `#+TAGS:` option line.

If you want a defined set of tags in all files except your journal, you can use `org-tag-alist` but put an empty TAGS option in the journal file. Then you can use dynamic tags and `%^g` in that one file.

**Update**

As noted in the comments, using an empty `#TAGS+:` line to prevent the `org-tag-alist` from being used in a specific file does not seem to work, despite being described in the manual. I'll investigate a bit more and file a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to put `#+TAGS: ` in the toprow of my journal.org file, but it did not prevent the fixed tags definitions from `org-tag-alist` to show up. Your method should only get me the tags used locally in that file, right?

Comment: Did you try either re-loading the file or hitting `C-c C-c` on the TAGS line to apply the change? The org manual mentions this case directly: "If you have globally defined your preferred set of tags using the
variable ‘org-tag-alist’, but would like to use a dynamic tag list in a
specific file, add an empty TAGS option line to that file..."

Comment: yes, but what is the point of using the `%^g` mechanism in the capture code then? If I have to relocate the headline after I have made it to press `C-c C-c`?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. An options line like `#+TAGS:` is applied automatically when an org file is loaded, even if it is loaded via a capture template. However when you first type in the option line, it is not immediately applied. You need to close and re-visit the file, or you need to use `C-c C-c` to tell org that you want to read/apply that line.

Comment: Hm, I have `#+TAGS:` as the first line, and I have reloaded the whole emacs, but when adding entries to my journal file all predefined tags show up. and if I add tags afterwards, by using C-c C-c, the same set of tags show up..

Comment: Yes - just tried it myself and the empty TAGS option does not seem to work as described in the manual. Perhaps a bug. What happens if you specify one or more tags there, instead of an empty line? I tried with `#+TAGS: journal` and a capture template using `%^g` and it seems to do what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to set my tag alist in a different way on a per directory basis. There is no clean way but it's possible.

I will start with the negative results of my investigation:

1. Setting `org-tag-alist` as a buffer-local on `org-mode-hook` has no effect.
2. Setting `org-tag-alist` as a file/directory-local has no effect.

The underlying reason is that org-mode computes `org-current-tag-alist` from `org-tag-alist` almost immediately after starting and uses `org-current-tag-alist` afterwards. The extension points (1) and (2) above run too late to be useful.

Another option is to override `org-current-tag-alist` on `org-mode-hook`:

```lisp
      (setq org-current-tag-alist
            (org--tag-add-to-alist my-org-tag-alist
                                   org-current-tag-alist))))
```

but be aware that this fails in some scenarios. For example, after calling the agenda `org-current-tag-alist` is recomputed for every agenda file.

The more robust option seems to be setting a before-advice. See the following example taken from my `init.el` that prepends a tag alist to the global one when under the `~/gtd/` directory:

```lisp
(defun my-org-gtd-tag-advice (&rest _)
  (when (string-prefix-p (expand-file-name "~/gtd/") buffer-file-name)
    (setq-local org-tag-alist
                (org--tag-add-to-alist
                 '((:startgroup . nil)
                   ("@casa" . ?c) ("@oficina" . ?o) ("@viaje" . ?v)
                   (:endgroup . nil)
                   ("PROJECT" . ?p))
                 (default-value 'org-tag-alist)))))
(advice-add #'org-set-regexps-and-options :before #'my-org-gtd-tag-advice)
```